# Distinguishing between SSL certificates

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

We have one Android and iOS mobile app in which there is one SSL Certificate pinned. Now I want to know that what kind of certificate is pinned in the both apps? (Leaf, Intermediate or Root). Is there any way to distinguish between this certificates. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have look [this](https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/install-ssl-certificate-on-android/)

Answer (score 1):

General indicators for different certificate types are:

## Root certificate

- is usually self-signed: `issuer` field matches `subject` field. Public key stored in the certificate can be used to validate the signature of the certificate.
- `Basic Constraints` certificate extension is presented and `isCA` attribute is set to `true`.

## Intermediate CA certificate

- is not self-signed: `issuer` field doesn't match `subject` field.
- `Basic Constraints` certificate extension is presented and `isCA` attribute is set to `true`.

## Client certificate

- usually is not self-signed: `issuer` field doesn't match `subject` field. `Subject` field contains information about the entity who owns the public key in the certificate.
- `Basic Constraints` certificate extension is absent or is presented and `isCA` attribute is set to `false`.